# HTML Email and Google Maps

Tags: html, html-email

I'm creating an html email.  On Outlook and GMail, the email format is correct.  But with Google Inbox the formatting gets messed up.  When I inspect the email in Inbox it shows that google adding extra code for google maps.  Ive done the research on possible solutions but none seems to work.  Here are two samples of what I've done from the research.  I replace @ADDRESS1 with the users address before sending out the email.

```
<td style="width: 45%;">
    <span class="" style="color: #000; font-size: 12px; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">
        <a rel="nofollow" href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color: #000; border: none;">&nbsp;@ADDRESS1</a>
    </span>
</td>

<td style="width: 45%;">
    <span rel="nofollow" class="" style="color: #000; font-size: 12px; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; text-decoration:none;">
        &nbsp;@ADDRESS1
    </span>
</td>
```

When I inspect the email.  This is what is added to the code:

```
<td style="width:45%">
    <span style="color:#000;font-size:12px;font-family:'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif">
        <a rel="nofollow" href="#m_-3542100051568633109_" style="text-decoration:none;color:#000;border:none">&nbsp;43478 GOLDEN MEADOW CIRCLE</a><a href="https://maps.google.com/?q=43478+GOLDEN+MEADOW+CIRCLE+%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09+%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09+%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09+%0D%0A%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09+%0D%0A%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09+%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09+%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09+%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09+%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09+%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09+%0D%0A%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09+%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09+%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09+ASHBURN+VA+20147&amp;entry=gmail&amp;source=g" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://maps.google.com/?q%3D43478%2BGOLDEN%2BMEADOW%2BCIRCLE%2B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2B%250D%250A%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2B%250D%250A%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2B%250D%250A%250D%250A%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2B%250D%250A%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2BASHBURN%2BVA%2B20147%26entry%3Dgmail%26source%3Dg&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1523385602990000&amp;usg=AFQjCNHtFzuxkGzIBkMPomWrrIXWB_iz_w">
    </a></span><a href="https://maps.google.com/?q=43478+GOLDEN+MEADOW+CIRCLE+%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09+%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09+%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09+%0D%0A%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09+%0D%0A%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09+%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09+%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09+%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09+%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09+%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09+%0D%0A%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09+%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09+%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09+ASHBURN+VA+20147&amp;entry=gmail&amp;source=g" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://maps.google.com/?q%3D43478%2BGOLDEN%2BMEADOW%2BCIRCLE%2B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2B%250D%250A%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2B%250D%250A%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2B%250D%250A%250D%250A%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2B%250D%250A%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509%2BASHBURN%2BVA%2B20147%26entry%3Dgmail%26source%3Dg&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1523385602990000&amp;usg=AFQjCNHtFzuxkGzIBkMPomWrrIXWB_iz_w">
</a></td>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated

**Update**

Just to clear it up.  I don't want Google to add map links to my addresses.  Because Google is adding the maps, its messing up my formatting in Google Inbox.  In fact I don't want any map information at all

Comment: I usually go with `staticmapmaker` site. It hasnt failed me yet

Comment: Thanks but its more that I dont want the map added to my email.  But staticmapmaker seems useful for a future project thanks

Comment: I have linked to google maps before and you can use coordinates or the search phrase. Can you update your question to add in what you are passing to the emails _before_ Gmail changes it?